# Azure pipelines to deploy to many customers

Tags: azure-pipelines

We're building a SaaS product where we to have 100s if not 1000s of customers.

Each tenant will identical apart from some configuration differences.

I've seen suggestion that this can be achieved via a pipeline per customer each running of the same yaml file.

This seems like it might not scale too well?

Are there any best practice recommendations on this?

Comment: To confirm the requirements, you may share the following information. 1. The service you use(Build Pipeline or Release Pipeline). 2.What are the different configurations you need (variables,agents or others)? Then I can try to figure out how to set the pipelines to meet your needs

Comment: We're using pipelines with YAML. Each tenant will have a few variables such as certs, credentials etc. The infrastructure is being built using terraform driven by the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Yaml template to be used by all tenants.

For different variables:

You could try to set the Variables in **“Variables”** option and select the **“Let users override this value when running this pipeline”** option.

[image: Set Variables]

In this situation, tenants can customize variables (modify/add)when queuing a new build.

[image: Edit Variables]

In Yaml file, you could use the **$(variables)** to reference variables so that you can replace variables that need to be changed.

Here is a doc about the [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax).